# Generator and list return different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-itertools

I'm trying to take in a generator, where each element is a list/tuple/iterable, that have equal length and return a separate generator for each index of the elements.

When I hard code the indexes in `split_feat2` below it works as expected. However when I use a list comprehension or append to a list and return it produces incorrect results.

I checked my logic and tried returning a list of lists instead of a list of generators by substituting the `()` for `[]` in the comprehension and it yielded correct results so I have no idea where the issue is.

Any insight into why it's acting the way it is would be greatly appreciated.

```
def split_feat2(gen):
    G = tee(gen, 2)
    return [(e[0] for e in G[0]), (e[1] for e in G[1])]

def split_feat(gen, n):
    G = tee(gen, n)
    return [(e[n] for e in g) for n, g in enumerate(G)]

def split_featlist(gen, n):
    G = tee(gen, n)
    return [[e[n] for e in g] for n, g in enumerate(G)]

test = lambda:((i^2,j+i) for i, j in enumerate(range(10)))

print("This is what I want")
t = split_feat2(test())
print(list(t[0]))
print(list(t[1]))
print(t)

print("\nBut I get this output")
t = split_feat(test(), 2)
print(list(t[0]))
print(list(t[1]))
print(t)

print("\nWhen I want this output but from generators instead of lists")
t = split_featlist(test(), 2)
print(list(t[0]))
print(list(t[1]))
print(t)
```

The above code outputs the below:

```
This is what I want
[2, 3, 0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 10, 11]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
[<generator object split_feat2.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x00000219C794F7D8>, <generator object split_feat2.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x00000219C794F200>]

But I get this output
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
[<generator object split_feat.<locals>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000219C791DB48>, <generator object split_feat.<locals>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000219C794F150>]

When I want this output but from generators instead of lists
[2, 3, 0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 10, 11]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
[[2, 3, 0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 10, 11], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `n` variable has changed before you actually consume the generators. So when the function returned the list of generators it's at `n - 1` (the function parameter `n`). So in your example both generators use the same index: `1`. To understand what I mean look at this simple example:

```
>>> list_of_list = [[0, 1]]*20
>>> index = 1
>>> gen = (item[index] for item in list_of_list)
>>> print(next(gen))
1
>>> index = 0
>>> print(next(gen))  # changing index "changed the generator"
0
```

In your case the loop constantly changed `n` (not manual intervention like in my example) but when the generators are executed it's fixed for all created generators at the same value.

#### Solution

You need to "fix" the current value of `n` in some way for each iteration. One possibility is `map` with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
def split_feat(gen, n):
    G = tee(gen, n)
    return [map(itemgetter(n), g) for n, g in enumerate(G)]
```

The `itemgetter` is immediatly created with the "current" `n` value, so the result will be as expected.

That's not the only ways to achieve the desired result. You could also use a function that creates the generator. The function will "remember" the current `n` (like a closure) and also work like you expect:

```
def split_feat(gen, n):
    G = tee(gen, n)
    def create_generator(it, n):
        return (item[n] for item in it)
    return [create_generator(g, n) for n, g in enumerate(G)]
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems obvious now that you've explained the behavior. Great explanation, by the way.